# CRM 2011 PRM Portal over https

Tags: iis-7, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Has anyone deployed the CRM 2011 PRM portal and had it working over https?

The ServiceContext.GetUrl(page) method seems to return the correct URL, but with port 80 post-fixed:

i.e. https://example.com:80/cases/editCase?CaseID=52560671-2fdb-e011-9599-00505682001c

Trying to figure out a way to track down if this is due to IIS configuration or the ServiceContext library that is doing this.

Comment: If you are interested in the Dynamics product range and its environment I kindly invite you to follow this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2)

Answer (score 0):

Can you double-check that the port 80 is in fact a result of calling GetUrl or is it the result of being passed through a UrlBuilder object. If the UrlBuilder is at fault you can call the PathWithQueryString property to omit the host and port values.

```
var url = new UrlBuilder(ServiceContext.GetUrl(page));
url.QueryString.Set("CaseID", id.ToString());
var path = url.PathWithQueryString;
```

If you need to keep the port value, it can be updated manually.

```
url.Port = Request.Url.Port;
```

This should not be an issue with your IIS configuration.